# Merge three arrays with ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ramda.js

I've recently started using Ramda to work with responses from JSONAPI and I am having some trouble dealing with complex relationships.. I have a big array with three smaller arrays, and I need to merge the three smaller arrays, but each array has a different property. I need one array with those three different properties.

For example:

```
const bigArray = [[...], [...], [...]] 

arrayOne = [
  { 
    id = 1,
    attributes = {...},
    specialProperty1 = {...}
  },
  { 
    id = 2,
    attributes = {...},
    specialProperty1 = {...}
  }
]

arrayTwo = [
  { 
    id = 1,
    attributes = {...},
    specialProperty2 = {...}
  },
  { 
    id = 2,
    attributes = {...},
    specialProperty2 = {...}
  }
]

arrayThree = [
  { 
    id = 1,
    attributes = {...},
    specialProperty3 = {...}
  },
  { 
    id = 2,
    attributes = {...},
    specialProperty3 = {...}
  }
]
```

Identical id's represent the SAME person. i.e. id 1 in arrayOne is referencing the same person as id 1 in arrayTwo. Therefore the attributes are the same as well. The only difference between these three arrays are the special properties. I need the entire object of each special property to be merged so that all three special properties are in the object with the corresponding id.

Like this:

```
const newArray = [
  { 
    id = 1,
    attributes = {...},
    specialProperty1 = {...},
    specialProperty2 = {...},
    specialProperty3 = {...}
  },
  { 
    id = 2,
    attributes = {...},
    specialProperty1 = {...},
    specialProperty2 = {...},
    specialProperty3 = {...}
  },
]
```

ALSO, this is being returned in a promise.All, so it is important to note that the three smaller arrays are all in one big array. I think this is what's tripping me up the most and I'm having trouble figuring out which Ramda methods to use to reference the three arrays within the big array.

Comment: 1) flatten the big array 2) group by id 3) join

Comment: 4) ....  5) Profit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to index by the `id` property of each array, then merge each corresponding array elements by their matching `id` and their contents. Then finally extract the values of the outer indexed objects.

```js
const
arrayOne = [
  { 
    id: 1,
    attributes: {},
    specialProperty1: {}
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    attributes: {},
    specialProperty1: {}
  }
],

arrayTwo = [
  { 
    id: 1,
    attributes: {},
    specialProperty2: {}
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    attributes: {},
    specialProperty2: {}
  }
],

arrayThree = [
  { 
    id: 1,
    attributes: {},
    specialProperty3: {}
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    attributes: {},
    specialProperty3: {}
  }
],

fn = R.pipe(
  R.map(R.indexBy(R.prop('id'))),
  R.reduce(R.mergeWith(R.merge), {}),
  R.values
),

newArray = fn([arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree])

console.log(newArray)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```